# Logistic Regression Odd Ratio

Tags: odds-ratio

I am doing logistic regression in R on a binary dependent variable with only one independent variable. I found the odd ratio as 0.99 for an outcomes. This can be shown in following. Odds ratio is defined as, $ratio.odds(H) = \frac{P(X=H)}{1-P(X=H)}$. As given earlier $ratio.odds(H) = 0.99$ which implies that $P(X=H) = 0.497$ which is close to 50% probability. This implies that the probability for having a H cases or non H cases 50% under the given condition of independent variable. This does not seem realistic from the dataset as only ~20% are found as H cases. Please give clarifications and proper explanations of this kind of cases in logistic regression. What should I do further to solve this question?

Comment: Is there any chance you could post your output from R?

Comment: I'm not sure your interpretation of the odds ratio is correct. You show an *odds*, an odds ratio is the ratio of two odds.

Comment: Thanks Kontorous,                                                                                                       I am hereby adding model summary and OR calculation.

Comment: glm(formula = H ~ X, family = binomial(), data = data)
Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-1.8563   0.6310   0.6790   0.7039   0.7608  
Coefficients:
                            Estimate      Std. Error      z value     Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)    1.6416666    0.2290133     7.168      7.59e-13 ***
   X                   -0.0014039   0.0009466    -1.483      0.138    
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)
    Null deviance: 1101.1  on 1070  degrees of freedom

Comment: Null deviance: 1101.1  on 1070  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 1098.9  on 1069  degrees of freedom
  (667 observations deleted due to missingness)
AIC: 1102.9
Number of Fisher Scoring iterations:4

Answer (score 3):

It seems like your interpretation of *odds ratio* (OR) is not correct $\frac{P(H = 1 | X)}{1 - P(H = 1 | X)} = \frac{P(H = 1 | X)}{P(H = 0 | X)}$ is an *odd* [$odds(X)$] not an *odd ratio*.
The *odds ratio* would be $\frac{odds(X)}{odds(X')}$ where $X'$ is a new set of values for your predictors. It is impractical to have several predictors change values at the same time so the *odds ratio* is most often defined for $X'$ differing from $X$ by only one of its elements (if you see $X$ as a vector of values/predictors).

Consider the following logistic model :

$log (\frac{P(H = 1 | X)}{P(H = 0 | X)}) = \beta_0 + \beta_1x_1 +\beta_2x_2$

Then the *OR* of that model in regards to the variable $x_1$ would be $OR(x_1) = \frac{\frac{P(H = 1 | x_1 + 1, x_2)}{1 - P(H = 1 | x_1 + 1, x_2)}}{\frac{P(H = 1 | x_1, x_2)}{1 - P(H = 1 | x_1, x_2)}}$

You can see that $x_1$ takes two different values but every other variables stay the same. And because $x_1$ only increased by one you have the *special* case (actually the most common case when people are computing *OR*) where your *OR* is directly linked to your estimated parameters.

$OR(x_1) = \frac{e^{\beta_0 + \beta_1(x_1 + 1) +\beta_2x_2}}{e^{\beta_0 + \beta_1x_1 +\beta_2x_2}}$ which simplifies into $OR(x_1) = e^{\beta1}$.
That is true with all parameters of your model.

So what $OR(x) = 0.99$ actually means is that for each 1 unit increase of $x$, everything else being kept the same, your *odds* is multiplied by $0.99$ ($e^{\beta1}$). So $0.99* odds(x) = odds(x + 1)$ which implies that $odds(x) > odds(x + 1)$ thus meaning that high values of $x$ are more prone to be met for $H = 0$.

Hopes it helps,

Comment: Nicolas, Thanks a lot! As i can understand from your answer that higher value of concerned covariate i.e the only independent variable that i am considering are more effective to reduce the probability of p(H=1). That is probability of occurrence of H adversely effected at higher values of x??

Comment: That's right, an odds ratio is always computed in regards to a specific independent variable of the model (here you only have one). It is not as straightforward as the probability of H = 1 but rather as the increase of that probability (here it looks like it is a slight decrease, as X is growing P[H = 1] slowly decreases as odds(X -1) < odds(X). This is confirmed by your other comment where it is shown that the beta coefficient for X is negative, giving an hint that your sigmoid curve is decreasing over X.

Comment: Thanks Nicolas! But, what should i say regarding the "This does not seem realistic from the dataset as only ~20% are found as H cases" in the question? How to explain this?

Comment: This is not related to your OR, the way you derived P(H = 1| X) from your OR is not correct so the result you got is not as well ! And even though you compute for some individuals P(H = 1| X) > 0.2 that is totally normal as you are conditionning H on X ! That is you are computing "Given the profile X how sure am I that the response should be H = 1. It is unrelated to your fraction of obsrevations with H = 1 ?". It is a whole other issue and is more broadly related to how logistic regression works so it should have its own thread I think

Answer (score 1):

Odds Ratios can be tricky to interpret sometimes, and I could try and explain it to you but I think this link would do the explanation better justice that I would: [How do I interpret odds ratios in logistic regression?](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/mult_pkg/faq/general/odds_ratio.htm)

As for the probability (which I am assuming you obtained through your log odds ratio), I think you need to delve into your data to see why you're seeing such a peak, it is most likely related to that. And also, you could calculate the **change in log odds** and **change in odds** for your independent variable to help you understand the changes per unit increase (also explained in the link above).

Hope that helps!